# Merging repositories override commits

Tags: svn

I have been trying to merge **3 subversion repositories together** yesterday, and I am running into strange issues I cannot understand. I hope some of you can bring some additional insights.

In the subversion server, I first copied the major repository I want to use as a basis for the future:

```
$ cp main new
```

This creates a new repository, that I can checkout normally.

Then, I created subfolders in this repository :

```
$  svn mkdir svn+ssh://me@svn.website.se/spacemetric/svn/new/public --message "Added the public folder to merge video repository."
```

I dumped the content from my other repository into a file, which I then loaded into the newly created subfolder :

```
$ svnadmin dump public >  /disk/nas-files/website/shared/me/svnstuff/public_last.dump
$  svnadmin load . --parent-dir public < /disk/nasfiles/website/shared/me/svnstuff/public_last.dump
```

Now, I have a new repository that contains the content of both my main and public repository.

The next **I wanted to do is to move the content of new/public/trunk into new/trunk**, in order to be able to remove the public folder afterwards. That would allow me to work with only one repository in the future.

For this, I used tortoise, and selected all the folder in trunk and right-click dragged them into the new/trunk and selected "Move to"...

Everything seemed fine. . . for a while.

**Then I realized that the last two weeks of commits in new have been overriden by really old commits of the public.**

I do not understand why this could have happened, since I clearly performed a move operation.

Could someone bring me some insight on this? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you do the "move to" in a working copy on your computer, or in the repository browser? If on your computer, did you actually commit the move?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by overridden?  Can you show the output of `svn log` of new/trunk and new/public/trunk?

Comment: Thanks for answering. The move to was done on my local machine, and committed indeed.

Comment: By overriden, I mean that revision 14273 in my case, that used to commit a specific file; now actually shows a 4 year old commit message instead. And all the files uploaded to the server via commits in the past 2 weeks are absent from the working copy, and the commits have been replaced apparently with other messages.